# Font Size Differs in report

Tags: jasper-reports, font-size

I have developed a simple app with JSP and I use *JasperReports* to generate reports from my app.

I've made a report in *iReport 5.6.0* with Arial font size 8 and when I preview in *iReport* it looks just fine. The report shows up in the right format with Arial size 8.

Then I try to run the report from my JSP app using *JasperReports*. The report also shows up with 
Arial font but in different size. It's 10.

This is my current conditions :

1. I use font extension for Arial .

2. I use font embedded.

3. I've copied the font extension .jar file to my app classpath directory.

4. My app runs in linux Centos server.

I need the report generated from my app in Arial size 8.

How to make the font size in my app report to 8?

the following is the report template (.jrxml) :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="blind_formulaa" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="57694596-349a-4ac7-a40a-18a6f2643ca9">
    <parameter name="pridformula" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="reportPath" class="java.lang.String"/>

    <field name="no" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <field name="idformula" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="idbahanbaku" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="satuan" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="ops" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="qty" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="kodeblind" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="nama" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="kodeexact" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="idproduk" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="tglstatus" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="namaproduk" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="batchno" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="batchsize" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="jumlahhalaman" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="nodokumen" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="3" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="134" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="12" y="67" width="53" height="20" uuid="926fbc5b-16e9-4599-bed4-104925c91f55"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nama Produk]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="12" y="86" width="53" height="20" uuid="36c42f18-4198-4f1c-b138-b5a959365236"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[No. Batch]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="12" y="106" width="53" height="20" uuid="48f2f0f0-b81e-47cd-9b3f-abf76148ec34"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Exp. Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="318" y="67" width="57" height="20" uuid="315b5b7c-4fe9-465e-8943-20d8bb881f01"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Besar Batch]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="318" y="86" width="57" height="20" uuid="b4bb4630-2835-4320-a99d-308728513fac"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[No. Dokumen ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="318" y="106" width="57" height="20" uuid="71c84878-81cf-4d2a-aa36-2f2d865317ff"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Top">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Tgl. Berlaku]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="86" y="67" width="225" height="20" uuid="aa38bab6-d4df-48c0-aaa1-f187590fe74a"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{namaproduk}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="118" y="26" width="318" height="26" uuid="42938971-883f-4642-b440-30b0ea3047c9"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isBold="true" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[STANDAR  FORMULA  DAN  PENIMBANGAN]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="16" width="555" height="1" uuid="f3fa42b0-edbc-4d52-a09c-a5a6424e0cd3"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="555" y="16" width="1" height="61" uuid="a246ad51-c25b-4887-8c39-236798e7d5d7"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="16" width="1" height="61" uuid="00b1e12f-3fd7-4a31-80de-8650c85cb0b3"/>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="411" y="0" width="104" height="16" uuid="b051ddc6-773f-4cff-a748-52fb5d0d4330"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Halaman 4  dari"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="520" y="0" width="32" height="16" uuid="935dd70e-dad1-44f0-8486-6d14d6a6d412"/>
                <box leftPadding="5"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{jumlahhalaman}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="12" y="20" width="240" height="37" uuid="72e47cc7-0803-40ed-9059-3a89b58d3ab1"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{reportPath}+"/abc.jpg"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="389" y="67" width="162" height="20" uuid="d2ecd8c4-6e5b-4c9f-8191-4c16fe1103a8"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{batchsize}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="87" y="86" width="190" height="20" uuid="165ad544-9c46-43d7-b50d-c21f861b3d35"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{batchno}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="77" width="1" height="57" uuid="9fe06dc7-c028-4cc4-b679-c336ef2d2ecb"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="555" y="77" width="1" height="57" uuid="10e61d68-1129-4443-976b-0215a266602f"/>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="390" y="86" width="162" height="20" uuid="984fc125-8ceb-4a84-b0a4-aa15c47cdf06"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{nodokumen}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="390" y="105" width="100" height="20" uuid="1eccd472-4537-47c6-86ab-54eb0dbbcbb3"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{tglstatus}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="65" y="67" width="21" height="20" uuid="c401aec0-8b90-473e-a583-6564aec7cc09"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="65" y="87" width="22" height="20" uuid="3f946edb-ce85-48b5-b0a3-f5b4f46ceafd"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="375" y="67" width="14" height="20" uuid="db744a7e-f01a-4f66-8aee-91aecb1db9c8"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="375" y="85" width="15" height="21" uuid="833f2097-c4e5-47d7-9afa-b1418baac06a"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="375" y="106" width="15" height="20" uuid="7a9eda84-ddf8-402f-b87f-2b4761385cf4"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="65" y="106" width="22" height="20" uuid="7359d15d-12df-4b3a-96b9-d06e8f94c45b"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="127" width="555" height="1" uuid="ff9d971a-1ddd-4aa7-9c39-09e2c58cf6ed"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="39" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="21" y="0" width="100" height="39" uuid="0317252f-6e4d-4890-bbd9-dc0ab3d7d533"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Kode Bahan]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="121" y="0" width="138" height="20" uuid="478d6ac5-3174-4f47-ad1a-e873454e8073"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Jumlah Per Batch]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="418" y="0" width="137" height="20" uuid="64e34ffd-a89f-4f33-8f56-c4e90a8dbff8"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isUnderline="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Paraf]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="38" width="555" height="1" uuid="adabe030-67ab-4f9c-ab04-a72f38a2f4c4"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="259" y="0" width="159" height="38" uuid="89aaf016-1484-4400-93c4-b3459a812476"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[No Analisa]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="21" height="38" uuid="5a4bec38-0b04-4394-991c-67b8d889c12f"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[No]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="418" y="19" width="66" height="19" uuid="d29f6349-b097-4cae-9259-d7df7891fb51"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[1]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="484" y="19" width="71" height="19" uuid="5b44a2d2-e2b1-41a9-92d5-4a30e14a0d30"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[2]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="121" y="20" width="37" height="18" uuid="aee07654-0bdc-41b2-842c-330095590e0b"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Unit]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="158" y="20" width="101" height="18" uuid="d3c85c2c-8d61-4ffc-96c2-30833055801e"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="true" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Jumlah]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="1" height="39" uuid="a03c6773-80c3-4df6-a63c-516b6fbf62bf"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="555" y="-1" width="1" height="39" uuid="3de7fb61-a721-4cdf-9cca-392a808b1fee"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="21" y="0" width="100" height="19" uuid="b710a1ff-4028-4369-92fe-7a39fadbca6f"/>
                <box>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{kodeblind}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="19" width="555" height="1" uuid="29d67237-7f41-40be-bf7c-9c7959db9089"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="418" y="0" width="66" height="19" uuid="1931746f-597f-4001-8747-bc96e92f3acd"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="484" y="0" width="71" height="19" uuid="128f3843-bb1b-455d-8dde-94fec1664b07"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="8"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="158" y="0" width="101" height="19" uuid="b5932422-3935-43d5-9c73-18278475b395"/>
                <box rightPadding="5">
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{qty}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="122" y="0" width="36" height="19" uuid="95f885c3-c6cb-4c51-9838-16cb8794e672"/>
                <box>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{satuan}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="2" y="-1" width="19" height="20" uuid="3248145b-30a4-4508-8aee-4bda11b0fa3f"/>
                <box>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{no}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="1" height="19" uuid="ccc5e243-caa0-40d2-9df3-ae325206cae2"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="555" y="-1" width="1" height="21" uuid="fb50a444-bf45-4f58-b631-67293b61cb19"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="227" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="427" y="7" width="100" height="14" uuid="817eae90-675c-49a9-9b2b-561096bec3ec"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Diperiksa Oleh,]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="417" y="62" width="1" height="89" uuid="d39cddde-20c3-4f4d-bb1e-e74b99cb8822"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="20" y="64" width="100" height="20" uuid="0d460b59-1b04-4726-81fe-0e8dd91feb8e"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[DISUSUN OLEH]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="62" width="554" height="1" uuid="85e34b4f-c279-4a86-a76e-3af8bcc5b565"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="214" y="64" width="100" height="20" uuid="a3a0ba96-2ba8-4735-ac40-29d359fa5e6e"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[DIPERIKSA OLEH]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="134" y="62" width="1" height="89" uuid="33e94f2f-ea21-4a89-bf62-3c27f6c4172e"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="158" y="124" width="79" height="27" uuid="d511e9d5-ca92-4bbf-bb3b-60533b515c6e"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[R&D MANAGER]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="151" width="554" height="1" uuid="60b78361-e155-4825-835f-52ed2bbf05d2"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="84" width="555" height="1" uuid="27fc1f19-b077-40d4-a1f2-a70f12ff1f86"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="448" y="127" width="72" height="20" uuid="0b9ff759-ba43-49f2-bfd3-007da76b025f"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[QA MANAGER]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="452" y="64" width="57" height="20" uuid="08bd1b3c-5345-407a-a693-4718b22cb8b8"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[DISETUJUI]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1" y="124" width="133" height="27" uuid="e9b9fc0f-fe46-4124-862c-54c0d13fc52f"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[R&D OFFICER/ASS. MANAGER]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="122" width="554" height="1" uuid="750bec23-0c2b-41be-a5b0-476e0b8e6f71"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="62" width="1" height="89" uuid="d86702ea-aa0e-4f4a-8b47-c99526693679"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="422" y="42" width="110" height="20" uuid="c5735acf-dd16-4063-b6ed-a58b999b419a"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="8" isBold="false" isItalic="false" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Spv / Leader Produksi]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="265" y="84" width="1" height="67" uuid="987199d2-3b5d-4c0c-bac0-7fd1f6630866"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="554" y="62" width="1" height="90" uuid="a2ee34c6-8b44-4fbf-8709-e1e688bca2d7"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="277" y="127" width="132" height="20" uuid="207769f8-bef3-4bed-b074-8816a2958bbf"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Arial" size="10" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[PRODUCTION MANAGER]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="3" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Maybe your report's template is wrong

Comment: @AlexK : I don't think the template is wrong. But if you don't mind maybe you could have a look on my template

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem with iReport at work, however in our case it sometimes worked (generated the text in correct font and size) and some times didn't (stuck at default font with size 10).

As it turned out, server-side we were using iReport in version **5.5.0**, and while some people generated their `.jasper` report files with correct desktop iReport version, others used newer desktop iReport **5.6.0** which failed to generate a report file compatible with older server-side version.

After we settled on one version (which we decided to be the older **5.5.0** to avoid changes on server side) the problem has been solved.

---

**tl;dr:** Remember to generate your reports with the same version of iReport that you use to print them.