# Increase in font size is not reflected in pdf generated. But reflected in preview

Tags: jasper-reports

Using ireport 5.6.0 editor. When I generate the pdf file the increased font size is not getting reflected. If I increase it to 100 also its just generating text with font size 10. Any ideas on why this issue.

Comment: Post your jrxml file

Comment: I answered a similar question, maybe the issue is related to yours http://stackoverflow.com/a/39565783/5385022

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using an older jar while generating the pdf. But when I used the jar files available withing the installation path of iReport the problem was resolved.